# Symfony Dynamic Form issues with displaying related data

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

I have a Form where I want to show the villages(dropdown) related to the district, but it is giving me following error.

Initially I thought the error must be due to addListener but when I commented the error was still there.

> Expected argument of type "string", "App\Entity\District" given at
> property path "district".

Following are the codes:

Form

```
        ->add('district', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => District::class,
            'choice_label' => function (District $district){
                return $district->getDistrictName();
            }
        ])
    ;

    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, District  $district  = null): void {
        $positions = null === $district ? [] : $district->getVillages();

        $form->add('village', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Village::class,
            'placeholder' => '',
            'choices' => $positions,
        ]);
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();
        
            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getVillage());
        }
    );

    $builder->get('district')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $event->getForm()->getData());
        }
    );
```

District.php

```
#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'district', targetEntity: Village::class)]
private Collection $villages;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->villages = new ArrayCollection();
}
....
public function getDistrictName(): ?string
{
    return $this->district_name;
}

public function setDistrictName(string $district_name): static
{
    $this->district_name = $district_name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection<int, Village>
 */
public function getVillages(): Collection
{
    return $this->villages;
}
```

Village.php

```
#[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'villages')]
private ?district $district = null;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getVillageName(): ?string
{
    return $this->village_name;
}

public function setVillageName(string $village_name): static
{
    $this->village_name = $village_name;

    return $this;
}

public function getDistrict(): ?district
{
    return $this->district;
}

public function setDistrict(?district $district): static
{
    $this->district = $district;

    return $this;
}
```

Controller

```
#[Route('/admin/add-product', name: 'add-products', methods: ['GET','POST'])]
public function addProducts(Request $request): Response
{
    $product = new Product();
    $form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    return $this->render('admin/index.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}
```

Product

```
<?php

    namespace App\Entity;
    
    use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    
    #[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProductRepository::class)]
    class Product
    {
        #[ORM\Id]
        #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
        #[ORM\Column]
        private ?int $id = null;
    
        #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
        private ?string $product_name = null;
    
        #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
        private ?string $size = null;
    
        #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
        private ?string $unit = null;
    
        #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
        private ?string $district = null;
    
        #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
        private ?string $village = null;
    
        #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
        private ?string $date = null;
    
        public function getId(): ?int
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
    
        public function getProductName(): ?string
        {
            return $this->product_name;
        }
    
        public function setProductName(string $product_name): static
        {
            $this->product_name = $product_name;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getSize(): ?string
        {
            return $this->size;
        }
    
        public function setSize(string $size): static
        {
            $this->size = $size;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getUnit(): ?string
        {
            return $this->unit;
        }
    
        public function setUnit(string $unit): static
        {
            $this->unit = $unit;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getDistrict(): ?string
        {
            return $this->district;
        }
    
        public function setDistrict(string $district): static
        {
            $this->district = $district;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getVillage(): ?string
        {
            return $this->village;
        }
    
        public function setVillage(string $village): static
        {
            $this->village = $village;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getDate(): ?string
        {
            return $this->date;
        }
    
        public function setDate(string $date): static
        {
            $this->date = $date;
    
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your Product entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encountering this error because your form is bound to your Product entity, which includes the variable $district as a string type property. As a result, any changes made in the district form field are automatically synchronized with the corresponding property in the entity.

I can suggest two options to address this situation:

**Direct Entity Relationship**:
Consider establishing a direct relationship between the Village entity and your Product entity. By doing so, you can define an association between them, which will allow you to easily manage and access village information related to a product.

**New FormType for Village:**
Alternatively, you can create a dedicated FormType specifically for the Village entity. This FormType will define the structure and validation rules for capturing village-related data. Then, within your existing Product form, you can add a field that utilizes the Village FormType. This approach is useful when you want to encapsulate village-specific form logic separately from your Product form.